# CheckBox state of a CellTemplate in ListView

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, resourcedictionary

i am trying to use styles to prevent from repeting code, by putting them in a Resource Disctionary.

My question is, when we have a GridViewColumn in a ListView, which one of the columns have a DataTemplate, and in that DataTemplate we have the CellTemplate with only a CheckBox, can we bind the CheckBox state when the DataTemplete is in a ResourceDictionary?

What i have is this in my XAML:

```
<ListView Name="listView">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberPath="{Binding [1]}"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberPath="{Binding [2]}"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberPath="{Binding [4]}"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberPath="{Binding [5]}"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberPath="{Binding [6]}"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberPath="{Binding [7]}"/>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsThreeState="False" IsChecked="{Binding [8]}" Unchecked="CheckBox_Changed" Checked="CheckBox_Changed"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

And i am trying to do something like this in the Resource Dictionary:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListViewCheckboxCell">
    <StackPanel>
        <CheckBox IsThreeState="False" IsChecked="Make reference"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

And the values in that column is always a bool.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did seems correct. You'll now have to write

```
<GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource ListViewCheckboxCell}" />
```

The template will be taken into account, you can leave exactly the same template than the original in your resource dictionary: The binding is dynamically resolved, so when the XAML will be read, bindings will automatically be set to the related object, following what you indicated

Comment: But i don't have the option AutoGenerateColumns enabled, i bind the columns from the source into the columns in the ListView. And so I do this `<GridViewColumn DisplayMemeberPath="{Binding [#]}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource ListViewCheckboxCell}"` but by doing this it will appear the bool value instead the CheckBox. It's where i am having a problem...

Comment: Could you please post the entire XAML code for your ListView? I think I have an idea about your problem, I bumped into almost the same problem some days ago. If possible, please edit your original post adding the entire code for your ListView & your original collection the list is bound to (ItemsSource)

Comment: I have added my Listview code. The ItemsSource is a table that i will get from a database. But the column from the table that i will bind isn't always the same. I will use this checkbox template in other windows, and the column that i will bind have a different index.

Comment: So, if I understood correctly, the checkbox will be bound to a different column in database for each column? I need to know what you are getting from database, and what are the columns. If what I think is what you have, I'd encourage you to create a `Dictionary` from the values in DB linking a key (your column details) to its value(the checkbox), hence you'll only have to bind to Key & Value without any more hard coded binding with magical numbers

Comment: Yes isn't always the same Column because it will be different Tables from the same DB. The Columns from 1 to 7 are Text and one of them is a Date, but the last column is a bool. Example of the row (Nvarchar, Nvarchar, Nvarchar, Nvarchar, Date, Nvarchar(but is a boolean)). What you mean when you say a Dictionary from the Values in DB?

Comment: Are you familiar with MVVM & DataBindings? If so, I'd advice you to get your data in your ViewModel, and save it in a Dictionary. For example, assuming that you get Strings & bools from DB, create a `Dictionary<String, Boolean>`. Then, bind this dictionary to your listview, and you can just leave the columngeneration to true in your listView, it will handle it automatically